# Making a line plot of a set of values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I wish to obtain the line plot for the following vectors in MATLAB:

`x=[0    0.6923    0.4615    0.2308    0.0769    1.0000];`

and

`y=[0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.6667    1.0000];`

I used the command
`plot(x,y);` to obtain the default line plot of MATLAB.

However, for some reason, the plot shows up like this: [Incorrect Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtq4g.jpg)

The scatter plot of the values can be seen as follows: [Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbVqP.jpg)

Upon inspecting the scatter plot, it can be seen that the points fit a curve, but can be simply connected to the next neighbour by a line segment (The usual way MATLAB does) instead of the zig zag line.

**Is there any way to fix Figure 1?**

And, Why does MATLAB end up connecting two different points that are not in succession ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `plot()` function does draw the line in exactly the order you specified your points. I guess you are looking for a plot with a line starting at the left most point continuing until the right most point. To reach this goal you have to sort your points by ascending x-values.

```
x=[0    0.6923    0.4615    0.2308    0.0769    1.0000];
y=[0    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    0.6667    1.0000];
[x,idx] = sort(x);
y = y(idx);
plot(x,y,'o-');
disp(x);
disp(y);
```

This produces the following output:

> 0.00000   0.07690   0.23080   0.46150   0.69230   1.00000
>
> 0.00000   0.66670   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000   1.00000

[image]